# Mapbox Geocoding and Directions APIs

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, mapbox

I am a real newbee regarding coding, but i have a question about the following tutorial https://bl.ocks.org/danswick/40bd3337b8e0231bdd89.

Instead of hitting enter to get a result. How can i implement autocomplete in this tutorial? Like so

[MapBox Autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JepQg.png)

I searched all over the MapBox docs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`autocomplete` is an optional parameter in the [api request](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#forward-geocoding). You'll need to add it to your request, and then also handle it in the UI. I would suggest looking at how this [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder/) does it.